# Installing memcached on Amazon Linux

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, memcached, ebextensions, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to use `memcached` for PHP on a Amazon Linux EC2 instance. In my PHP script when I call `$mc = new Memcached();` the following error gets thrown in `/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`:

```
[06-Sep-2020 00:49:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcached' not found in /var/app/current/memcached.php:8
Stack trace: #0 {main}
  thrown in /var/app/current/memcached.php on line 8
```

Calling `php -m` I do not see `memcached` listed, which I assume means it is not installed.

So, first I tried:

```
sudo yum install memcached
sudo yum install php70-pecl-memcached
```

along with edits to `/etc/php.ini` to include

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

as outlined [here](https://blog.lawrencemcdaniel.com/install-memcached-on-amazon-linux/) but no luck.

So next, I tried the suggestion as outlined by AWS support [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-pecl7-modules-php/) for Amazon Linux EC2 v1. Looking through `cfn-init-cmd.log`, the package `libmemcached` is installed successfull, however, the script fails when it tries to install `memcached` as it is unable to find `/use/bin/pecl7` as per the command `01_install_memcached`. For reference, my full script in `.ebextensions/memcache.config` was:

```
packages:
  yum:
    libmemcached-devel: []

commands:
  01_install_memcached:
    command:  /usr/bin/yes 'no'| /usr/bin/pecl7 install memcached
    test: '! /usr/bin/pecl info memcached'
  02_rmfromphpini:
    command: /bin/sed -i -e '/extension="memcached.so"/d' /etc/php.ini
  03_createconf:
    command: /bin/echo 'extension="memcached.so"' > /etc/php-7.3.d/41-memcached.ini
    test: '/usr/bin/pecl7 info memcached'
```

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: If you ssh to the EB instance, can you manually install it and make it work? This would allow you to verify the steps that you are trying to automate.

Comment: I'm bit of a newb when it comes to interpreting YAML and `.ebextensions`, so I ran the following based on the script: 'sudo yum install -y libmemcached-devel', next `sudo pecl install memcached`, then removed the line for `memcached.so` from `/etc/php.ini/, created a new file `/etc/php.d/41-memcached.ini` with the line `extension="memcached.so"`, and lastly restarted the instance...and then success! So two changes from the script, firstly use `pecl` instead of `pecl7`, and second the dir for the `memcached.ini` file to reflect what was on the instance

Comment: And just tested a revised script, and it seems to work. I guess I'm a little surprised that this is required to get memcache to work with PHP on a Amazon Linux 2 instance as I thought it was installed by default.

Comment: @qwertytam especially when you need it to use AWS Elasticache. Seems like a bit of a fail there to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this slightly revised `.ebextension` script worked. I'm no AWS/Linux/PHP expert, so there is probably a more correct way to approach this.

```
packages:
  yum:
    libmemcached-devel: []

commands:
  01_install_memcached:
    command:  /usr/bin/yes 'no'| /usr/bin/pecl install memcached
    test: '! /usr/bin/pecl info memcached'
  02_rmfromphpini:
    command: /bin/sed -i -e '/extension="memcached.so"/d' /etc/php.ini
  03_createconf:
    command: /bin/echo 'extension="memcached.so"' > /etc/php.d/41-memcached.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding memchache directly into installation

```
packages:
  yum:
      libmemcached-devel: []
       memcached
commands:
  01_rmfromphpini:
    command: /bin/sed -i -e '/extension="memcached.so"/d' /etc/php.ini
  02_createconf:
    command: /bin/echo 'extension="memcached.so"' > /etc/php.d/41-memcached.ini
```